# Загибающийся уголок на CSS

Tags: css, css-animation

Ребята помогите разобраться как доделать hover на картинке.

Вот то что должно быть:
[image: Вот то что должно быть]

А [вот](https://jsfiddle.net/yurask/w8cs08q6/1/) что получилось у меня

Не могу придумать как убирать/показывать белую картинку, но без ее трансформации.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VYJKKM - пример того что вышло (only webkit)

Только вот с поддержкой clip-path не очень (полифилы на него не видел ибо не искал), да и его использование в этом случае, как мне кажется, не ахти

наверное, лучше использовать js, например вот это http://www.netzgesta.de/curl/

Comment: Спасибо, этот вариант как раз то, что нужно.
js плагин, который вы предлагаете, видел и пробовал с его помощью сделать этот эффект. Но к сожалению у него ховер как-то нервно работает, да и всунуть туда три картинки не так просто, т.к. он рассчитан на одну картинку тегом img.

Answer (score 0):

Увеличь отогнутый угол так, чтобы под него можно было бы спрятать половину div-прямоугольника с подложкой, а потом аккуратно уменьшай этот прямоугольник в след за картинкой с отогнутым углом так, чтобы левый верхний угол прямоугольника при этом не высовывался 
[image: введите описание изображения здесь]

Comment: спасибо за ответ.
Белая картинка это второе изображение и если ее уменьшать теряется смысл загибания уголка.

Answer (score -1):

Оберните в `DIV` с `overflow: hidden` и пусть из угла выезжает вслед за уголком.

Comment: я так уже делал)))
дело в том, что эта белая картинка является как бы вторым слоем и из-за ее узоров, она не должна двигаться или уменьшаться, а только обрезаться вертикально с левого верхнего угла.

Comment: [Вот](https://jsfiddle.net/yurask/nd651th3/) немножко переделал, что бы понятно было почему ее уменьшать или двигать нежелательно.